# convert JSON file to a hashmap in java with error Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashMap out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json

I have the following code and json file. The JSON file looks like

[
 {
 "AC": 1.1324 
},
{
 "AD": 0.64956 
},
{
 "AE": 1.4508 
},
{
 "AF": -0.94481 
}
]

I would like to convert it to a hashmap so that when the key is "AC", the corresponding value is 1.1324. I am not sure if my code was wrong or if the format of my json file is wrong! I appreciate your patience in reading my question!

I am aware of there are similar posts that kind of have the similar exceptions in my problem but I do not have much experience in java so that I can not figure it out by reading other posts.

I have the following code in java but I am not sure why I have the exception. Basically, the json file is the input parameter "file" for the following method. "featureWeights" is the field in the class

```
   public Map<String, Double> setMapFeatureWeights(File file){

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FileInputStream curIn = setFileInputStream(file);

    try {

        TypeReference<HashMap<String,Double>> typeRef
                = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Double>>(){};

        featureWeights = mapper.readValue(curIn, typeRef);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if (curIn != null)
            try {
                curIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    return featureWeights;
}


public FileInputStream setFileInputStream(File file){
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}
```

The error I got is as below:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashMap out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.FileInputStream@145f66e3; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:762)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:758)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:316)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3066)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2214)
at conifer.SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.setMapFeatureWeights(SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.java:132)
at conifer.SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.makeSyntheticData(SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.java:269)
at conifer.SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.run(SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.java:219)
at briefj.run.Mains.instrumentedRun(Mains.java:62)
at conifer.SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.main(SimplePhyloSimulatorFixedTreeRateMtx.java:247)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading it in as an array of maps.

A json map would look like this:

```
{ "AC": 1.1324, "AD": 0.64956, "AE": 1.4508, "AF": -0.94481 }
```